# adding a contact while creating an activity

Tags: visualforce, ui

This must not be a new idea. 
A salesperson starts to enter an Event, realizes their Contact isn't yet added to the CRM, and would like to add on the fly. 
Can we do this without canceling the entry and losing all that they have started to enter?
Things I have tried -

- a visualforce link to a New Contact page,
- a custom link to New Contact
- a custom button to New Contact

these all WON'T appear on the Edit screen. Any solutions? thanks all

Comment: Also, a formula field doesn't work b/c again it doesn't show on the edit screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a New Contact link on the sidebar which meets the functional need. Simple, not as elegant as I wanted, but does the job. Kind of obvious in retrospect.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own VisualForce page for adding events.  You can then control what appears on the edit page without losing the information for the event.

You can also enable 'Show Quick Create' from the Setup|Customer|User Interface.  This will allow you to quickly create a contact from the Contact lookup dialog without leaving the Event edit page.  There are pitfalls to doing this with the primary one being that it by-passes validation rules.  You should search google 'avoid salesforce quick create' and draw your own conclusion as to whether this will work in your specific environment.

Comment: Is this the only option - a full on swap of the New Event page? It is surprising to me there aren't work arounds.  Yes, must avoid the quick create option.

Comment: In a VF page,  <apex:inputfield value="{!Event.whoId}"/> shows to add a single contact, not the multiple contacts, as a regular new Event lookup.

Comment: Appears to be a known limitation https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BOg0IAG